# Socket / Http Request

Tags: sockets, http, protocols

What is the difference between using socket to connect to a site, and simply making an HTTP request?

Does the connection established by the sockets make it possible not to authenticate during the request?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between using socket to connect to a site, and simply making an HTTP request?

The act of *using socket to connect to a site* is more basic than *making an HTTP request* — the former is required by the latter, since a HTTP/TCP request cannot be sent without an established connection.

> Does the connection established by the sockets make it possible not to authenticate during the request?

HTTP neither implies authentication.